# rails OR query based on multiple checkbox selections

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

This seems like it should be a common problem but I'm having trouble finding an answer. Basically I want to have a form with 10 or so checkboxes which I'm creating with `check_box_tag`. When the form is submitted I want to generate a query that return all records that match ANY of the checked selections. So, the number of checked selections will vary.

So, for example, if I have

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

I want to generate something like

`Book.where("author_id = ? or author_id = ?", params[authors[0]], params[authors[1]])` if there are two boxes checked, etc.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
Book.where(author_id: [array_of_author_ids])
```

You need to collect author_ids from params first

Comment: Based on his code so far I think he has that as params[authors].  So you've got it. In rails 2.3 I'd have to do: Book.all(:conditions => ["author_id IN (?)", params[authors])  ... Does where() really allow me to do it like you did in 3.x?

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thank you. I was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be. (I'd vote you up but not quite there yet, rep-wise.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar, this is how I achieved this. It's pretty clever (at least I think so. :))

I created a query model that serializes the query column (text field) in JSON. I use a form to get the query data from the user with selection fields.

```
class BookQuery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books



  # loop through each foreign key of the Book table and create a hash with empty selection
  def self.empty_query
    q = {}
    Book.column_names.each do |column_name|
      next unless column_name.ends_with?("_id")
      q.merge column_name => []
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using Author as an example below:
    <%= form_for @book_query do |f| %>
      <% for author in Author.all %>
        <%= check_box_tag "book_query[query][author_ids][]", author.id, false%>
        <%= author.name %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Save Query" %>
    <% end %>

When this form is submitted you ended up with parameters like this:
When the form is submitted it generates this parameter:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXX", "book_query"=>{"query"=>{"author_ids"=>["2", "3"]}}, "commit"=>"Save Query"}
```

Now in the BookQuery controller's create action you can just do what create function always does:

```
def create
  @book_query = BookQuery.build(params[:book_query])
  if @book_query.save
    flash[:success] = "Book query successfully saved."
    redirect_to ...
  else
    flash[:error] = "Failed to save book query."
    render :new
  end
end
```

But by default rails serializes the data in hash type:

```
1.9.3p194 :015 > pp BookQuery.find(9).query
BookQuery Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "book_queries".* FROM "book_queries" WHERE "book_queries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
"--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\nauthor_ids:\n- '2'\n- '3'\n"
=> "--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\nauthor_ids:\n- '2'\n- '3'\n"
```

In BookQuery model, add the following:

```
serialize :query, JSON
```

But rail would change the IDs to string:

```
1.9.3p194 :018 > query = JSON.parse(BookQuery.find(10).query)
BookQuery Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "book_queries".* FROM "book_queries" WHERE "book_queries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
=> {"author_ids"=>["2", "3"]} 
1.9.3p194 :019 > query["author_ids"]
=> ["2", "3"]
```

What I did then is override the attribute accessors in BookQuery model:

The below has to be done because the hash returns strings, not ids in integer.

```
def query=(query)
  query.each_pair do |k, v|
    if query[k].first.present?
      query[k].map!(&:to_i)
    else
      query.except!(k)
    end
  end
  write_attribute(:query, query)
end

# just want to avoid getting nil query's
def query
  read_attribute(:query) || {}
end
```

To find book with this query, you can simply add this function to your Book model:

```
def self.find_by_book_query(book_query, options = {})
  options[:conditions] = book_query.query
  find(:all, options)
end
```

Now you get a customizable query string based on the model definition Book and everything works like the Rails way. :)

Comment: A load of that is redundant. If you'd si

Comment: Sorry, your comment seems to be cut-off. What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: hi fatshu, sorry it was cut off because i was going to delete it after writing it on my iphone last night and couldn't.
A lot of this stuff is redundant... _in this scenario_ , i planned to delete my comment because what you gave here is specific to the problem you faced (rather than the question above). For this question - if he wanted to save queries - you'd only store the authors as serialized, and not JSON style. then just chuck it into a find as alper does above.
Again: apologies, great code for your situation, not so much for this question.

Comment: I see. I thought the problem was generic like mine, where I had to handle multiple records associated with the "Book". But I see now how I misunderstood.